# Delphi XE needs 20 seconds to start

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

After reinstalling Delphi (and installing the Update 1 on top of it) it needs 19-20 seconds to start.
In the beginning it shows nothing (about 17 seconds).
Then it finally shows the splash screen and the modules it loads. I already have DelphiSpeedUp plugin.

How can I make is start faster? Or is this the typical loading time for Delphi XE with Update 1?

---

Update:
'Process monitor' shows that Delphi accesses the HKLM\system\currentControlSet\Services\TcpIp\Parameters and stays there to about 10 seconds. No other registry key or file is accessed after this, for 10 seconds!!!!!!!
Probably is the Embarcadero's protection that tries to 'call home'. I guess I have to unblock Delphi in my firewall. Maybe if it can call home it will load faster.

Also, does anybody tried to make Delphi XE .Net free?

Comment: You can't get rid of the .net dependency

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was so damn right!!!! By default, my firewall block all programs except Firefox and Thunderbird. So, I let Delphi XE call home and guess what: It loaded in 10 seconds!

With the firewall off it connected to two different IP addresses and exchanged some data.
One of the addresses is server155.autometadqa.com (64.34.176.155:80).
Probably I will have to install some network package tracker to see what kind of data it sent out of my computer and in which qualities (KB, MB).

**Solution1-Make Delphi fast**
Let Delphi through the firewall.

**Solution2-Keep computer isolated from internet**
Don't let Delphi through the firewall.

I know absolutely nothing about Embarcadero except that they make Delphi now. But since they had money to buy it, it means it is a big company and because of this case, also respectable. So, I will let Delphi through the firewall in order to cut those 20 seconds to 10.

Comment: Well, you can still upgrade but put Delphi in your firewall program. The start is a bit slower but otherwise it seems to work also without internet.

Comment: This means it is the `AQTime` plugin from `Automated QA` keeping Delphi from loading fast. You should contact them to remove the `phone home` feature.

Comment: I dont have a firewall for going out, yet I get that.  Worse, since teh latest update, it freezes 20 times day (or more).  Process Monitor shows that all its doing is looking up  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters every 10 seconds...   AArrghhhh. !!!!

Answer (score 7):

20 seconds for click-on-icon to IDE-ready-for-input?

Don't change anything! I wish mine was as fast as that!

Comment: Yes. But Delphi XE without Update 1 was loading in less than 8 sec.

Answer (score 4):

Try to add following line in your **HOSTS** file:

**127.0.0.1   server155.autometadqa.com**

Repeat this for all servers if there are more then this one.

Answer (score 1):

Is Delphi phoning home, or is it checking for updates?

What happens if you change your firewall setting back and simply [turn off the check](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=790&tstart=0)?  In XE, the registry key is:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0\AutoRun\UpdateCheck
```

Comment: The key was already deleted from registry. I got two REG files from Internet to enable/disable automatic updates. Right after I installed it first time. Strange that they don't have a setting for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the auto-update, if indeed that is the cause of the delay, by removing these registry keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\AutoRun\UpdateCheck    
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\AutoRun\UpdateCheck
```

I'm not sure that you need to remove both, but I always do.  And this is for a 64 bit machine.  On a 32 bit machine you need to remove:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\AutoRun\UpdateCheck    
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\AutoRun\UpdateCheck
```

I do this because the auto-update doesn't play nice with UAC on Delphi 2010 (perhaps they fixed that in XE) and in any case, I don't like the idea of my production compiler changing without my consent.

Comment: Hi David. I already have two reg files that enable/disable that feature. Its not that.

Comment: Sure, but perhaps for other readers then the auto update is relevant.